# alert when connection drop during file upload

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, file-upload, connection

How can I in javascript do alert if somehow during file upload (100MB) the connection drop?

Right now what I have is, if user upload a file, it will show loading bar in the screen, and if it finished it will remove the loading bar. However problem is when somehow internet connection drop. The loading bar will still be there so user thought they are still uploading while actually nothing happen anymore.

the way I upload file is standard php (move_uploaded_file)

How can I handle this?

I tried navigator.onLine, but it does not work.

note: the way I test this will be, I try to upload file (100MB usually will take 30 seconds) and in the middle I'll try to cut off the wifi connection purposely. What I'm hoping is the page will show alert saying connection drop.

Comment: use the error events of ajax to hide the bar and warn the user.